# Unable to test @DataSourceDefinition with JPA using @Deployment

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, glassfish, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to create a simple Java EE application consisting of a class holding the `@DataSourceDefinition` and `@Stateless` annotations, an Entity and a Service used to save/load entities from a jdbc datasource that should be produced by the `@DataSourceDefinition`. I can deploy my application to my GlassFish server fine, however if I try to run my test class, I bump into an error when creating my war in an `@Deployment` method.

```
    [2015-08-25T15:41:07.626+0100] [GlassFish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1440513667626] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method]]

[2015-08-25T15:41:07.630+0100] [GlassFish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1440513667630] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/jdbc/DataSourceDefinitionPersistence__pm), (applicationName=fabf46ab-7970-49d4-9c25-20a452e71745) }
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:275)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.post(TemplateListOfResource.java:166)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/jdbc/DataSourceDefinitionPersistence__pm), (applicationName=fabf46ab-7970-49d4-9c25-20a452e71745) }
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:589)
    ... 76 more]]
```

My DSD class is as follows:

```
@DataSourceDefinition(name = "java:app/jdbc/DataSourceDefinitionPersistence",
    className = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource",
    serverName = "localhost",
    portNumber = 5050)
@Stateless
public class DataSourceDefinition {
}
```

My entity I have created simply holds getters and setters for an id field and a value field.

The service class that performs jpa operations is as follows:

```
@Stateless
public class Service {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void saveNewEntity() {

        Entity entity = new Entity();
        entity.setValue("value");

        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    public List<Entity> getAllEntities() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT _entity FROM Entity _entity", Entity.class)
            .getResultList();
    }

}
```

My `persistence.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/DataSourceDefinitionPersistence</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Now when running my test class with Arquillian I receive the error shown in the stack trace. The test class deployment is as follows:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {

WebArchive war =  ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
        .addPackages(true, DataSourceDefinitionAnnotationPuTest.class.getPackage())
        .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml");

System.out.println(war.toString(true));

return war;

}
```

The test fails in the deployment method and it seems like the `persistence.xml` is being used to look for the persistence unit before the datasource has been defined. If I build and deploy the application on the server and then try running a test the test passes and my test operations work fine. However I need to have it working so that I can run my test using an `@Deployment` method and not have the app already deployed on the server. Is there a way to force the `@DataSourceDefinition`class to do its job before the `persistence.xml` file is used to lookup the datasource?

If that's not the issue could you please point me towards where I'm going wrong with my attempt at producing this.

Edit:
Needs to work with a `glassfish-remote-arquillian` profile.

Comment: I've seen similar things with Wildfly. I haven't used glassfish for some time, but my guess is that the persistence lookup is being done before the datasource is created. Can you add in a datasource file, or maybe try annotating a `@Startup` bean with the datasource def?

Comment: @LightGuard I'll have a look at adding an `@Startup` bean with the `@DataSourceDefinition` tomorrow. What do you mean with regards to adding in a datasource file? For my purpose manually creating a datasource through asadmin commands/admin console is not suitable unfortunately if that's what you mean.

Comment: Have you tried using a glassfish-resources.xml file for your tests? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/giyhh.html

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to use the glassfish-resources file, as the application is solely used to check whether JPA is working with `@DataSourceDefinition`. I had a look at the `@Startup` annotation but it didn't seem to affect the result after a couple of different attempts. I'm using ShrinkWrap to deploy the test war, so I don't know if there's a way to make my `DataSourceDefinition` be accessed before `persistence.xml`?

Comment: Not sure. Start double checking documentation. Sounds like it's more of a glassfish issue and not Arquillian.

Comment: @LightGuard I think it's possibly a spec issue as some of the WildFly guys were bumping into the same issue with a similar application. They managed to work around it on an embedded profile by adding a twophase bootstrap to the `persistence.xml` but I couldn't find any solution for GlassFish. Thanks for the suggestions though! I feel like the problem would be solved if the Arquillian behaviour and timings were changed. Might have to try a very hacky solution.

Comment: Possibly a spec issue. For the problem you're having, I doubt Arquillian is part of the issue. Arquillian has already sent the archive to the server to be deployed, it's basically handed it off until deployment is done.